# select columns having only one type of group (mysql)

Tags: mysql

I'm using Mysql.

I have two tables that contain information about Excel sheet.

First table contains document information like *sheetID*, *createdBy*, *dateOfCreation*.

Second table contains details of each excel sheet: *sheetID*, *colName*, *colType*.

A sheet can have several *colName*.

*colType* can be A,B or C.

*sheetID* is linked to each other via foreign key.

**Example**:

TABLE 1:

```
1   ABC.XLS    GAURAV
2   XYZ.XLS    FOOBAR
3   QWE.XLS    FOO
4   QZXC.XLS   BAR
```

TABLE 2:

```
1   name    A
1   place   A
1   amount  B
1   link    C
2   name    A
2   website C
3   name    A
4   home    A
4   name    A
4   fname   A
```

I need to write a query that returns all those sheets that have only one type of data.

Like in this example *sheetId* 4 has only "A" type of data.

**Edit 1:** 
The solution provided by scaisEdge worked .

Can this query be extended to find the sheet which has all the 3 types of columns. Like in above example *sheetId* 1 has all the three types.

Comment: i was able to get the types that are present in each sheet 

SELECT sheetID,colType  FROM `table2` a JOIN table1 b ON a.`sheetID` = b.`sheetID` GROUP BY sheetID,colType.
I am nable to figure out how to count if a sheet has more than 1 type

Answer (score 0):

You can use a  not in sublect

```
 select t1.* 
 from table_1 t1
 inner join table_2 t2 on t1.sheetDI = t2.sheetID
 where t2.sheetID not in (select distinct sheetID from table_2 
                           where coltype <>'A')
 and t2.colType = 'A'
```